# Null hypothesis testing

Tags: stata

I ran a regression and have an estimated regression line that looks something like this (where a*b is the interaction term)

```
Y=B+B1*a+B2*b+B3*a*b
```

I want to find the p-value for a test of the null hypothesis that the impact of 'b' on 'Y' equals zero when a=2.

I know F-test would work but I don't know how to include a=2 in the command. I was thinking of something like

```
test b b*a if a ==2
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a model of the type:

[image]

We can get the effect of X1 on Y by taking the partial derivative with respect to X1:

[image]

If we want to know the effect of X1 on y when X2 is 2, we just fill in 2 for X2. Then, we are left with a simple linear combination which can be calculated by `lincom` or `margins` (`margins` is the recommended way).

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. qui reg price c.mpg##c.weight

. margins, dydx(mpg) at(weight = 2)

Average marginal effects                        Number of obs     =         74
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : mpg
at           : weight          =           2

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |    396.401   185.0749     2.14   0.036     27.28083    765.5212
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. lincom mpg + c.mpg#c.weight * 2

 ( 1)  mpg + 2*c.mpg#c.weight = 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         (1) |    396.401   185.0749     2.14   0.036     27.28083    765.5212
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```